# Appfabric caching for database dependency

Tags: appfabric

We believe the AppFabric caching is a good fit for the caching requirement. However, we also want to implement some sort of database dependency, i.e. the cache should sync with the backend database asynchronously. The read-through and write behind feature seems interesting, could anyone please help point us a direction how can we leverage these features in achieving the auto sync behavior between the appfabric and database? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlDependency can be used to notify to your application about modifications in database. To use this you need to enable service broker on database level, please go through these [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588572/what-are-the-limitations-of-sqldependency) before implementation this solution

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(databaseSqlToBeMonitered, connection))
    {
       SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
       dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler((a, b) =>
                                {
                    //Remove data from cache
                                });

       command.ExecuteReader().Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @PhilPursglove Here I'm talking about SqlDependency, in this way we can achieve support for dependency support. Nowhere I have mentioned about AppFabric supports dependency.